# Remove element using remove(), but its property still exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a problem with `remove()`. After I remove the `<svg>`, its property still exist, I want to delete it completely. The properties such as position, and other css property. If I can have some explanations about `remove()` and `empty()`, it will be more appreciated. Thank you very much for the help.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#play').click(function() {
    $('#container svg').remove();
  });
  $('#test').text($('#svg1').position().left)
}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:600px; height: 400px">
  <svg height="130" width="150" style="position:absolute; left:200; top:200;" class="ui-widget-content" id="svg1">
    <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>
    <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue">
  </svg>
</div>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<h1 id="test"></h1>
```

Comment: You are just binding the event handler to remove the element, the `svg` will not be removed till the button is clicked. In the meantime you have set the `text` of `h1` element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting initial position of `svg` because your code is placed directly in `document ready`. When you put this code

```
$('#test').text($('#svg1').position().left)
```

inside your `click` event handler and look at the console output, you'll see:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read **property** 'left' of undefined

So, it means, that the element along with **all** its properties **is** removed. Though, the text of `#test` element won't change because of the above js error.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#play').click(function() {
    $('#container svg').remove();
    $('#test').text($('#svg1').position().left)
  });
  
}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:600px; height: 400px">
  <svg height="130" width="150" style="position:absolute; left:200; top:200;" class="ui-widget-content" id="svg1">
    <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>
    <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue">
  </svg>
</div>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<h1 id="test"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add type="button" to your button.  Button's default type is submit.  So button is submitting the page and you are getting a reload.

Comment: Not when there is no form

Answer (score 0):

Not much to say...

```
  $('#play').click(function() {
    $('#container svg').remove();
    //Here #svg1 does not exist anymore
  });
  //Here #svg1 exists
```